# Unable to migrate mail to 'google apps mail ' with Other domain user credentials

Tags: c#, email, dns, credentials

I am trying to Migrate mail on 'Google Apps Mail'.
When i give Admin credentials it get migrated successfully.
But when i use Domain user credential it shows error "  Execution of request failed: ".

I want to migrate mails to user not to Admin User.Then why there is need of Admin credentials ?

I am using Google API Ver 2.

Thanx

Comment: Should ask this on superuser.com instead.

Comment: In place of telling user to move question from one place to another.I think we should help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Advanced tools.Under "User email uploads" just Check "Allow users to upload mail using the Email Migration API. (Administrators always have access to this API.) " Option
i will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using API to migrate, you can use [this online tool](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=14156%205077282021820947710) at Google Marketplace.